# For loop only changing the last value- Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running a for loop but it is only modifying the value of last entry not all the values.

```
import re
ht = """
    <tr>
        <td>03-31-2020_00.20.02.1135</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>03-31-2020_00.20.02.105</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>03-28-2020_05.10.01.7068</td>
    </tr>"""
```

```
for i in ht.split():
        if i.startswith("<td>03-31-2020"):
            htm = (ht.replace(i,'<b><font color="#ff0000">'+i+'</font></b>'))
print (htm)
```

--getting the output as below(just have modified the last entry not all matching entires)-

```
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>03-31-2020_00.20.02.1135</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <b><font color="#ff0000"><td>03-31-2020_00.20.02.105</td></font></b>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>03-28-2020_05.10.01.7068</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) method from `re` library to substitute the matching pattern with the replacement.

**Try this:**

```
html = re.sub(r"(<td>03-31-2020.*?</td>)", r'<b><font color="#ff0000">\1</font></b>', ht)
print(html)
```

**Output:**

```
  <tr>
        <b><font color="#ff0000"><td>03-31-2020_00.20.02.1135</td></font></b>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <b><font color="#ff0000"><td>03-31-2020_00.20.02.105</td></font></b>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>03-28-2020_05.10.01.7068</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks it was just short and crispy, it resolved my issue:)

Comment: If this answer answers your question Remember to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing problems mostly because every time you replace, you overwrite your `htm` variable.

Try to overwrite your `ht` variable instead:

```
for i in ht.split('\n'): 
    if i.strip().startswith("<td>03-31-2020"):
    ht = ht.replace(i,'<b><font color="#ff0000">'+i+'</font></b>') 
print (ht)
```

Answer (score 0):

In each loop you're replacing the variable `htm` with a new replaced substring, so you're only seeing the result of the last match.
What you should rather do is save the replaced value in a variable outside the for loop so you don't lose the results

```
import re
ht = """
    <tr>
        <td>03-31-2020_00.20.02.1135</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>03-31-2020_00.20.02.105</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>03-28-2020_05.10.01.7068</td>
    </tr>"""

htm = ""
for i in ht.split():
    if i.startswith("<td>03-31-2020"):
        htm += '<b><font color="#ff0000">'+i+'</font></b>' + "\n"
    else:
        htm += i + "\n"
print("htm", htm)
```

Although, I would suggest using regex to match and replace strings, much cleaner code.